# Trouble getting usb wifi to work - AC600 Realtek rtl 8811AU

Tags: wireless, realtek

I am...in over my head, and I apologize if this has already been asked and answered, but I did search, and had no luck (lots on rtl8812..). I used to use Ubuntu some back around when 12.04 came out, but haven't really done much since then and don't really know how to do anything. I bought a new (older, refurbished) desktop and wanted to get it set to dual boot win10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I also bought a usb wifi card, as the desktop did not come with one.

Specs: HP desktop, i5 processor, 8 gb ram, 2 tb hard drive
USB card (I realize I should have concerns about compatibility as I searched the Q & A on amazon and it says the newer kernels may not have support): [https://www.amazon.com/Adapter-EDUP-Wireless-External-Antennas/dp/B01CCMUN8C/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CCMUN8C)

Initially when I plugged in the stick, nothing at all happened. I first followed this tutorial: https://blog.danielscrivano.com/installing-rtl8812au-on-linux-for-wireless-dual-band-usb-adapters/ 
After I did those steps, my wifi card did work as it should. I could utilize the 5 ghz band and had blazing internet speeds. When I shut down the computer and turned it back on, the wifi stick no longer works. It's like Ubuntu doesn't even recognize it is plugged in (no lights on the stick, if I search for it, I cannot find it). After that happened, I tried various other online tutorials/fixes and nothing worked; this usb stick seems permanently disappeared.

I wish I had bookmarked everything I tried, but didn't and don't remember all that I have tried (so sorry :() But I fear that I have made 1 royal mess trying to get this thing installed.

As I said at the beginning, I am a Ubuntu noob and you will need to provide me with your 'dumbest' advice.

Thank you so much

Comment: Does it start working again if you do: `sudo modprobe 8812au`? If not, what is the exact response to the command?

Comment: Nothing at all happens when I enter that. 
brandon@brandon-HP-Compaq-6200-Pro-MT-PC:~$ sudo modprobe 8812au
brandon@brandon-HP-Compaq-6200-Pro-MT-PC:~$

Comment: After more searching, it is looking like a kernel issuue and maybe this was just an unlucky coincidence (I may have updated kernel at the same time as I installed my wifi stick). It looks like this thread may be what I need to fix it: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2340049   
I will update this when I get the chance to run the thread to completion (right now I'm off to church).

Comment: So, I finally figured out how to update to kernel 4.4.0-45, and my wifi stick still is not working. I even tried reinstalling the stick, and nothing happened. When I plug it in, nothing happens. When I type Chili's recommendation of `sudo modprobe 8812au` absolutely nothing happens. Any next steps/recommendations for me? I am stumped, about all I can think is if I try to boot in the older kernel (4.4.0-42 I think) every time i want to use ubuntu?

Comment: I suggest you try post #11 here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2339960&page=2&highlight=8812au

Comment: Thanks, just did post #11, still no luck. Ubuntu doesn't seem to identify the stick when I plug it in. After doing post #11, I jumped down to post #17. The first command shows `8812au                905216  0
`, the second command does nothing, the third command shows what I think is bad: `[  278.533115] 8812au: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  278.534484] RTL871X: rtl8812au v4.3.8_12175.20140902
[  278.534511] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8812au
`

Comment: I think it is fixed. I am currently connected to wifi. I read all the fine print and compared my problem with the user on the other thread that you helped and we seemed to have a very similar issue (except I never got error messages), so I started following the instructions at step #41, where you broke out the sledgehammer and plasma cutter. The step that seemed to make the difference was `sudo apt-get purge rtl8812au-dkms`. After a reboot, I plugged my stick in and it worked right away. I will proceed with caution and mark this as answered if still working after a few reboots. THANK YOU!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

rtl8812au-dkms build fails on ubuntu 16.04.2   kernel 4.8.0-41

wifi adapter: TP-LINK T4UH.

You can install a patched for the 4.8 kernel driver from Yakkety this way:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rtl8812au/rtl8812au-dkms_4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu5_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i rtl8812au-dkms_4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu5_all.deb
```

Disconnect the USB adapter cable, reconnect and magic.
Working TP-Link T4UH ac1200 usb 3.0

Based answer:

askubuntu.com/questions/884260/r8168-dkms-build-fails-on-ubuntu-16-04-2

writed for pilot6. Thanks you.

Another answer:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rtl8812au/+bug/1637059

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 18.04.1 the following worked perfectly for TP-Link T4UH ac1200 usb 3.0:

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

then restart the computer, the receiver light should start blinking.

as it is a laptop, one should also disable the internal Wifi:
you can look for the wifi kernel driver with:

```
lspci -nnk
```

then

```
sudo modprobe -r *the name of the internal wifi kernel driver*
```

in my case:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
```