# USB Wifi adapter Realtek 8811AU/8812AU not recognized

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, usb

I have freshly installed ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. My usb wifi adapter which works perfetcly fine in windows 10 in the same system (dual boot), is not recognized here. the chip of the adapter is a Realtek 8811AU/8812AU.

I have gone through various posts here to identify but could not find anything to work. By going through different posts, i am providing the o/p of some commands before hand only.

```
$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth           Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 18d1:4ee3 Google Inc. Nexus 4 (tether)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1b1c:1b37 Corsair 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:0a4d Logitech, Inc. G430 Surround Sound Gaming  Headset
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c246 Logitech, Inc. Gaming Mouse G300
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

```
$ sudo lshw -C network

*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 31
   serial: 40:8d:5c:ed:9f:2f
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.8-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:123 memory:df100000-df11ffff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: enp0s20f0u6
   serial: ae:42:24:15:38:31
   capabilities: ethernet physica
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.168 link=yes multicast=yes

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

Here is the output of the wireless info script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZPhd97zK5X/

Comment: You should also mention maker and model of the adapter. The output from lsusb does not say much this time,

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: the first step command lspci -nn -d 14e4: does not shows anything..so i guess its not a broadcom then?

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/837893/trouble-getting-usb-wifi-to-work-ac600-realtek-rtl-8811au

Comment: I fixed a similar problem on Debian by installing the `firmware-realtek` package from the non-free repository.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using this, https://medium.com/@at15/ubuntu-16-04-8811au-wireless-driver-d29d6929a50c

its just simple drivers download and installation for the specific chip which is Realtek 8811AU/8812AU

Comment: after restart, the wifi did not show again.

Comment: Those drivers are not very stable, as of today, none of the 11ac drivers for linux I have tried so far are usable.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my aROTaO USB-C Ethernet Adapter Hub 3-Port USB 3.0, (Thunderbolt 3) on my Lenovo Yoga 720-15ikb.

It works on the Windows Partition but not, if I plug it in on Ubuntu.

**Workaround:**
It works fine if I plug it in and **reboot** Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to compile and install driver from here: https://github.com/morrownr/8812au

The driver is not included in the kernel yet.